# Подскажите в чем ошибка?

Tags: python, json, python-3.5

```
import json

with open('report.json') as report:
    data = json.load(report)
    for i in data[0]['data']:
        if i['Conception'] == 'Salepoint1' and i['OrderType'] == ['Takeaway']:
            print(i['DishDiscountSumInt'])
```

Ошибка:

```
File "/Volumes/My Files/Python/iikoBot/gettingReport.py", line 40, in <module>
    data = json.load(report)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/json/__init__.py", line 268, in load
    parse_constant=parse_constant, object_pairs_hook=object_pairs_hook, **kw)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/json/__init__.py", line 319, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/json/decoder.py", line 342, in decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Extra data", s, end)
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Extra data: line 1 column 4752 (char 4751)
```

Структура report.json:

```
{ "data" : [ { "Conception" : null,
        "DishDiscountSumInt" : 6420,
        "DishDiscountSumInt.average" : 6420,
        "OpenDate.Typed" : "2016-04-22T00:00:00",
        "OrderType" : "Sale",
        "UniqOrderId.OrdersCount" : 1
      },
 ...
      { "Conception" : "Salepoint1",
        "DishDiscountSumInt" : 0,
        "DishDiscountSumInt.average" : 0,
        "OpenDate.Typed" : "2016-04-22T00:00:00",
        "OrderType" : "Takeaway",
        "UniqOrderId.OrdersCount" : 2
      }
    ],
  "summary" : [ [ {  },
        { "DishDiscountSumInt" : 153289,
          "DishDiscountSumInt.average" : 561.5,
          "UniqOrderId.OrdersCount" : 273
        }
      ],
      [ { "Conception" : "Salepoint1",
          "OpenDate.Typed" : "2016-04-22T00:00:00"
        },
        { "DishDiscountSumInt" : 14894,
          "DishDiscountSumInt.average" : 2978.8000000000002,
          "UniqOrderId.OrdersCount" : 5
        }
      ],
...
    ]
}
```

Comment: Проблема в json, Откройте его в редакторе и посмотрите на первой строке символы на позициях 4751-4752. Там какая фигня. Или в каком-нибудь онлайн-сервисе или редакторе поддерживающем json откройте и проверьте -- они выделят проблемное место

Comment: http://jsonlint.com/ в помощь